# Bind Control to DependancyProperty of container control

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have created a UserControl in Silverlight and added some dependency properties to it to expose selected options in the control to any other controls that use my control, how do I bind properties of something like a ListBox used in my control to the dependency properties of my control? I am currently using ElementBinding but I'm not too fond of ElementBinding in general... I was hoping there is some sort of relative binding but relative binding doesn't seem to provide the options I am looking for (but I don't think I actually understand relative binding very well)

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `UserControl` tha contains a `ListBox`, and you wish to expose your `ListBox` selected items from your `UserControl`?

I can think of a few options ...

1. Set the DataContext of the 'LayoutRoot' of your UserControl to itself, as [in this example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/the-mini-viewmodel-pattern/), you can then bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` to your corresponding property on your `UserControl`.
2. Use a ReltiveSource FindAncestor binding to navigate up the visual tree from your ListBox to your `UserControl`.
3. Use an `ElementName` binding, by giving your `UserControl` a name and referencing that in your `ListBox` binding.

Personally I favour (1), typically there will be more that one property you want to expose, making this the simplest solution.

Comment: Hi Colin, I failed to mention that I'm using Silverlight (added a tag for it) which means no FindAncestor etc...

Comment: OK - well (1) and (3) still apply. However, you can find a FindAncestor implementation here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/

Comment: Thanks Colin, 3 is what I am hoping to avoid (for no particular reason), 1 does give me a couple of ideas. I was actually hoping that there would be a 'standard' binding expression for this, like FindAncestor for WPF. The problem that I have found with setting a control's data context explicitly is that when you use them within databound container controls you have to agian do ElementName or Source binding as the control's DataContext is not the same as the containing control, so I suppose in most cases ElementName binding is the best idea. Or a custom binding helper, which I strongly dislike.

Comment: See the link for (1), you do not set the usercontrols datacontext to itself, you set the root of its layout. This ensures that the exposed properties of your usercontrol work as expected.